# MVC Design - From JS Control to PHP View

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller

Usually if I need some static HTML I send the request to a PHP Controller which calls the appropriate View and sends it to the client.

I recently realized that if I need static HTML while in JavaScript I can just call the view directly using an ajax get request for the file.

So essentially I have my JavaScript Controller Calling a PHP View file.

Is It O.K to bypass the PHP Controller and call the view directly from the JavaScript Controller?

I just want to make sure I have a solid MVC design in both PHP and JS

Comment: You should not be able to do this, in a well protected site structure. All the application-related files should reside outside document_root.

Comment: I agree with @tereško above. If you have any php files in your docroot besides your bootstrap file you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't have a bootsratp file I have CIn ...Control In....I was going through there but seems a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

> Is It O.K to bypass the PHP Controller and call the view directly from
>   the JavaScript Controller?
>
> I just want to make sure I have a solid MVC design in both PHP and JS

Absolutely not. It's not ok to bypass controllers in MVC. All interactions must be controlled through controller and it's a very simple rule. Otherwise you will end up with solid mess instead of solid MVC.

Comment: I'm still using the JavaScript Controller...as a substitute....it would be just like treating the file if it was client based ( and in the case of caching it is )

Comment: as it was noted in php chat room, for most of 'developers' MVC means "My Very Code".

Comment: I'm moving more state to the Client...so it will soon be My Vacant Code.

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP is just including some static HTML and sending it i will suggest to bypassing PHP to speed-up thinhs.